# Donut chart labels on DevExtreme for React

Tags: reactjs, charts, label, devextreme

I'm trying tyo generate donut charts with DevExtreme for React, and because of the lack of documentation adapting the code source from other frameworks. I can create the graphic with data received by props, but I am having a hard time trying to generate Labels for them.

Currently I can only use my arguments as legends, as seen here:
[donut chart with legend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJ6Vo.png)

And I needed it to be like displayed in labels, for example:
[donut chart with labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75u8o.png)

I'm using the library *DevExtreme React Wrappers* ansy component Donut is something like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import PieChart, {Series, Label, Legend, Tooltip} from 'devextreme-react/ui/pie-chart';

class Donut extends React.Component {

    render(){

        return (

                <PieChart
                    type={"doughnut"}
                    palette={"Soft Pastel"}
                    dataSource={this.props.dataSource}
                  >
                  <Legend
                      visible={true} // should be false because I don't want legends, but currently I need them
                      horizontalAlignment={"left"}
                      verticalAlignment={"bottom"}
                      margin={0}
                  />
                  <Series
                      argumentField={'arg'}
                  />
                  <Tooltip
                      enabled={true}
                      shared={true}
                  />
                  <Label //I've tried so many variations adapted from JQuery or Angular documentation, but nothing seems to work.
                      visible={true}
                      format={'fixedPoint'}
                      argumentField={'arg'}
                    />
                </PieChart>
         );
     }
}
export default Donut;
```

Any help would be really appreciated. :)

Comment: am facing exact issue , is this achievable in "@devexpress/dx-react-chart": "^3.0.5" ? –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Label is a part of a Series, so the Label tag should be placed within the Series. Series `argumentField` should be set to `'region'` (according to the [demo](https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/Charts/Doughnut/jQuery/Light/))

This is about configuring the Chart, but unfortunately the 18.1.5-alpha.10 version has a regression regarding the Label component. So I would recommend you the following:

1) downgrade `"devextreme-react"` to `"18.1.5-alpha.9"` and track [the issue](https://github.com/DevExpress/devextreme-react/issues/187)

2) modify the code in this way:

```
var data = [{
    region: "Asia",
    val: 4119626293
}, {
    region: "Africa",
    val: 1012956064
}, {
    region: "Northern America",
    val: 344124520
}, {
    region: "Latin America and the Caribbean",
    val: 590946440
}, {
    region: "Europe",
    val: 727082222
}, {
    region: "Oceania",
    val: 35104756
}];

class Donut extends React.Component {

    render() {

        return (

            <PieChart
                type={"doughnut"}
                palette={"Soft Pastel"}
                dataSource={data}
            >
                <Legend
                    visible={true} // should be false because I don't want legends, but currently I need them
                    horizontalAlignment={"left"}
                    verticalAlignment={"bottom"}
                    margin={0}
                />
                <Series
                    argumentField={'region'}
                >
                    <Label
                        visible={true}
                        format={'fixedPoint'}
                        connector={{ visible: true }}
                    />
                </Series>
                <Tooltip
                    enabled={true}
                    shared={true}
                />
            </PieChart>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: am facing exact issue , is this achievable in "@devexpress/dx-react-chart": "^3.0.5" ?